# csrf_token verification failed?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am a beginner and searched a lot about it but do not got any thing please explain why this error is coming.

I have used this code from here:

[JavaScript post request like a form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit)

Error is coming from the following code in my html template in under script tag:

This code is from Davidson Lima comment:

```
post("{% url 'savep' %}", {name: user_name, pass: user_pass, csrfmiddlewaretoken: $("#csrf_token").val()});
```

Here is the code of views.py

```
def save_login(request):
  x = request.POST['user']
  y = request.POST['pass']
  member = credentials(user_name=x, user_pass=y)
  member.save()
```

Error:

```
Forbidden (403)

CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
Help

Reason given for failure:

    CSRF token from POST has incorrect length.
```

Comment: probably you should use `$(".csrf_token")` or `$("#csrf_token")`

Comment: @eisanahardani don't work, but thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

It worked on firefox but not in google chrome,
We have to pass csrf_token that was stored at
**$(".csrf_token").context.cookie** location

```
post("{% url 'savep' %}", {name: user_name., pass: user_pass, csrfmiddlewaretoken: $(".csrf_token").context.cookie.split('=')[1]});
```

See doc, In order to work it on all browsers:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/csrf/